# How to clear the input field when sending message?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help a javascript-beginner out, I am fetching messages from an API and in the input-field it is possible to send a message.

I want the input field to be cleared when I click the button and send the message, right now the message is still there when I click on send. How can I make that happen?

https://love-happy-thoughts.netlify.app/
(if you try to send, you need more than 5 letters in the message to be able to send it)

https://github.com/AsaHildebrand/project-happy-thoughts/tree/master/code/src

```
import React from 'react';
const NewThoughts =({ newMessage, onNewMessageChange, onFormSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <label>
      <form
        className='message-section'
        onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
        <label
          htmlFor='messages'>
          <h2>What's making you happy right now?</h2>
        </label>
        <input
          className='message-area'
          id='messages'
          type='text'
          value={newMessage}
          onChange={onNewMessageChange}
        />
        <button
          className='submit-button'
          type='submit'>
          <span className='heart-icons' role="img" aria-label="heart-icon">❤️</span> 
            Send Happy Thought! 
          <span className='heart-icons' role="img" aria-label="heart-icon">❤️</span>
        </button>
      </form>
    </label>
  );
}

export default NewThoughts;
```

App.js:

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    
    import ThoughtsList from './components/ThoughtsList';
    import NewThoughts from './components/NewThoughts';
    
    import { API_URL, LIKES_URL } from './reusable/urls';
    
    export const App = () => {
      const [thoughtsList, setThoughtsList] = useState([]);
      const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState('');
    
      useEffect(() => {
        fetchThoughtsList();
      }, [thoughtsList]);
    
      const fetchThoughtsList = () => {
        fetch(API_URL)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(messages => setThoughtsList(messages))
      }
    
      const onNewMessageChange = (event) => {
        setNewMessage(event.target.value);
    }
    
      const onFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        const options = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ message: newMessage })
        };
        
      fetch(API_URL, options)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(receivedMessage => setThoughtsList([receivedMessage, ...thoughtsList]));
      }
    
      const onHeartLikes = (id) => {
        const options = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        };
    
        fetch(LIKES_URL(id), options)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(receivedMessage => {
          const updatedThoughtsList = thoughtsList.map(message => {
            if (message._id === receivedMessage._id) {
              message.likes += 1;
            }
            return message;
          });
            setThoughtsList(updatedThoughtsList);
          })
      }
    
      return (
        <div>
          <NewThoughts
            newMessage={newMessage}
            onNewMessageChange={onNewMessageChange}
            onFormSubmit={onFormSubmit}
          />
          <ThoughtsList
            thoughtsList={thoughtsList}
            onHeartLikes={onHeartLikes}
          />
    
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: event.target.value = "";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const onFormSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
       ... // your other codes
      setNewMessage('')
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

After submitting the form you can setNewMessage to empty string. Like this `setNewMessage("")`